# Spark grouping tuning

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Given following files:

- employees
- skills
- reports
- etc.

Between employees and each of the other files there is 1-to-N relationship, e.g. to one employee correspond multiple skills. Each file is between 500MB to 1.5GB and there are about 10 files in total.
For each employee, I want to aggregate/gather all the information from all the files (skills, reports, etc.) and write it to an XML structure:

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <skills>
      <skill>...</skill>
      <skill>...</skill>
      ...
    </skills>
    <reports
      <report>...</report>
      <report>...</report>
      ...
    </reports>
    ...
  </employee>
  ...
</employees>
```

I'm doing something along the lines:

```
val employeesRdd = employeesDf.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("employeeId"), r))
val skillsRdd = skillsDf.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("employeeId"), r)).groupByKey()
val reportsRdd = reportsDf.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("employeeId"), r)).groupByKey()
...

employeesRdd
  .leftOuterJoin(skillsRdd)
  .leftOuterJoin(reportsRdd)
  ...
  .toLocalIterator
  ... // write <employee> nodes one by one
```

Problem I have is that all groupByKey() operations are very slow, as in many hours long. And after running for so long it blows up due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. I'm using Spark 1.5.1 in local mode with about 20GB assigned to the jvm.

Answer (score 0):

partitioning of a Spark DataFrame should be best choice for you.

pertitioning will help in storing data for related information in neary by. so it help process to access required information fastly.

[offical doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)  , [doc](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-partitions.html)